# Installing one module using a JAR generated from a complete Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project with multiple submodules, organized as follow:

```
project-all/
  pom.xml
project-model/
  pom.xml
...
```

Where `project-all/pom.xml` is basically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.my.company.myprojectgroupId>
    <artifactId>pom-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../project-model</module>
        <!-- And so on... -->
    </modules>

</project>
```

And `project-model/pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my.company.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <relativePath>../project-all/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project-model</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- A bunch of dependencies... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I can generate a `project-model-2.0.1.jar` in the `project-model/target` directory using `mvn package` from the `project-all` directory.

I then need to install these in a local repository, but if I do:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=project-model-2.0.1.jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=.
```

...it fails because the `pom.xml` file within the `project-model-2.0.1.jar` is dependent on the parent `project-all`.

I can install it by specifying the artifact details in the command line, but I cannot specify, e.g., the dependencies.

Is there a way to either:

- Install the file as it is generated now without having to install all submodules?
- Generate a `.jar` containing a valid `pom.xml` that I can install using `mvn install:install-file`?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstand you, but: You never install jars that you _built yourself_  with `install:install-file`. Instead you run `mvn install` on the project and all the jars are installed automatically.

Comment: @JFMeier Maybe we have a weird setup. We have two projects, managed by two separate teams, where project `B` depends on project `A`. We don't have a shared Maven repository.  What we currently do is have a local repository shared by all developers on project `B` where we deploy project `A` when a new version comes out. Deploying to the local repository is where `mvn install:install-file` comes into place, but maybe there are other way to do so...

Comment: I would really advice you to set up a Nexus or Artifactory server to manage your artifacts, especially as you work cross different teams.

Comment: try installing the parent pom mvn install:install-file -Dfile=project-all/pom.xml -Dpackaging=pom

Comment: @imperezivan That's what I ended up doing, plus adding the original `pom.xml` from `project-model` when installing it.